# Arduino powered car not running when touching ground

Tags: arduino-uno, h-bridge, l298n

I hacked a cheap car I connected both motors to L298N Dual H-Bridge Motor Controller and all things are working good. Motors are running fast. But when I put the car on the ground to run. It runs so slow. I am using 4.5V for L298N.
What can I do to run it fast on ground?

I have tried PWM but it does not work.

What can be the causes of this?

Comment: Some measurements could help understand the issue.

Comment: What are you using to provide the 4.5volt?

Comment: The car's default battery back. It has space for 3 1.5V batteries. I am using that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It cannot draw enough current I suppose. When wheels are free-spinning, the load on motor is very small. When you put it on ground, the load increases, and it is slow because there is not enough current to drive the load

Comment: Yep more power is always the answer :)

Comment: The question is. How car was actually running with 4.5V batteries before i hacked it?
Was that power enough to run the car without motor driver and arduino?
Can you kindly explain this?

Comment: If you are powering stuff directly from Arduino, problems will arise due to fact that Arduino pins have limited current output. I suggest you create a driver circuit, with transistors and external power source. Transistor is for external source control.

Comment: I powered it with 9V battery. It does not work. When I was using 3 1.5V batteries, the voltage of the motor was 1.8V but when I powered it with 9V battery, it was 1.8V again. And it does not move on the ground.